# "I have been informed by Alex" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Wie sagt man *"I have been informed by Alex"* auf Deutsch?

Könnte die Aussage so übersetzt werden?

> Ich bin von Alex informiert geworden.
>
> Ich war durch Alex bescheid geworden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beide Aussagen sind an sich richtig (bis auf kleine Fehler), sie unterscheiden sich aber in der Zeit.

> Ich bin von Alex informiert worden.

kommt dem englischen Satz *I have been informed by Alex* am nächsten.

> Ich war von Alex informiert worden.

alternativ: *Mir wurde von Alex Bescheid gegeben*. Die englische Übersetzung wäre auch hier dann eine Zeit weiter zurück:

> I *had* been informed by Alex.

Comment: +1 Alex replied :-D

Comment: Informing is my thing, obviously.

Comment: Der zweite Satz hört sich nicht nur sehr untauglich an, er ist grammatikalisch auch nicht korrekt. _Bescheid geben_ verlangt Dativ, deswegen sollte es im Plusquamperfekt heißen _Mir war von Alex Bescheid gegeben worden_.

Comment: @jera Hatte es mir gedacht, dann streich ich es. Danke

Comment: @jera Ich war informiert worden wäre eigentlich der richtige Satz, oder?

Comment: @Alex _Ich war informiert worden._ ist die Plusquamperfekt-Form von _Ich bin informiert worden._ Meiner Meinung nach hört sich diese Form allerdings nicht untauglich an. Das ist nun man Plusquamperfekt, der, habe ich das Gefühl, vor allem im nördlichen Deutschland verwendet wird. Bitte korrigiert mich, ich bin aus Österreich, wo diese Zeitform sehr ungebräuchlich ist.

Comment: Genau genommen ist es noch immer nicht ganz korrekt: _Mir wurde Bescheid gegeben_ ist zeitlich gleichbedeutend wie _Ich bin informiert worden_ (sollte also in deiner Antwort nach oben rutschen). Zeitlich vor diesen Aussagen sind die Sätze _Ich war informiert worden_ und _Mir war Bescheid gegeben worden_ anzuordnen.

Answer (score 0):

> Alex hat mich informiert

or

> Alex hat mir Bescheid gegeben

or

> Ich wurde von Alex informiert / Ich bin von Alex informiert worden

Comment: Speziell bei Übersetzungsfragen würden wir gerne lesen "warum/wieso/weshalb" du deine Übersetzung richtig findest und *was* an der originalen Übersetzung möglicherweise falsch/ungeschickt sein könnte. SE ist kein Übersetzungsservice - Antworten wie diese, die nur aus dem übersetzten Text und keiner zusätzlichen Information bestehen, degradieren es aber potentiell dazu.

Comment: Dann liefere ich die Erklärung nach, Patricks Antwort ist nämlich deutlich
besser als die von Alex. Passivformen sind im Englischen viel häufiger als im
Deuschen. Deshalb lautet die Antwort auf die Frage "*Wie übersetze ich diese
englische Passivkonstruktion ins Deutsche*", wenn eine idiomatische Übersetzung
gefragt ist, häufig "*durch eine Aktivkonstruktion*".

Comment: @Uwe Ich akzeptiere und anerkenne, dass die *Übersetzung* besser ist - Leider nicht die *Antwort*.